# With two iPhones using separate SIM cards, can I use one to make a call from the other?

Tags: iphone, continuity, wifi-calling

I have two iPhones using separate SIM cards. I'm already able to answer incoming calls to one on the other – but how can I use one phone to make a call from the other?

And importantly, I mean calling ALL numbers, not just FaceTime users.

Thanks!